# Changing theorem/lemma... label to bold italics

Tags: fonts, formatting, theorems

For theorems in my contribution I use `\theoremstyle{plain}`. This style prints theorem label in bold italics, eg. 'Theorem 1.', which is followed by text in italics. How could I set 'Theorem 1.' to italics to match the theorem content?

I read related question

[Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/non-italic-text-in-theorems-definitions-examples)

but I was not able to extract the answer.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38264/5626 and change `\itshape` to `\itshape\bfseries` (and other settings accordingly).  But first of all: why on earth would you want to do that!?

Comment: Thanks. 1) I don't like bold up followed by italics, so I set everything to italics. 2) if 1) makes no sense, I simply don't like present scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the theorem scheme that you're after, called `mytheorem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% <name>
  {3pt}% <Space above>
  {3pt}% <Space below>
  {\itshape}% <Body font>
  {}% <Indent amount>
  {\itshape\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
  {.}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}% <Space after theorem heading>
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }#2}%
   \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}% <Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')>
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\lipsum[1]\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The key here is to include a theorem head specification (argument `#9`) in order to reformat the theorem number from `\textup` (or `\@upn`) to plain. Here's the *default* definition of the theorem head specification (associated with the `plain` style):

```
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
```

Note the forced `\@upn` (defined as `\textup`).