# Italicizing of amsthm package

Tags: theorems, italic, amsthm

I'm using the `amsthm` package, and I noticed that a remark is automatically italicized, while a theorem and a proposition are not.

What other keywords have their content automatically italicized by the package?

Edit: I did not define any theorem styles. I simply used

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample document.  By default `amsthm` defines no theorems, propositions or remarks, but provides theoremstyles for defining such.

Comment: take a look at this question: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is set by `\theoremstyle{#1}`. The possible values are `plain`, `definition` and `remark`. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]


\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{thm}
One plus one equals two.
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
One plus one equals two.
\end{lem}

\begin{prop}
One plus one equals two.
\end{prop}


\begin{defn}
Two is one plus one.
\end{defn}

\begin{rem}
One plus one equals two.
\end{rem}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is based on the the style that you define the environment with. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides three styles by default (`plain`, `definition` and `remark`), but you can define your own styles using `\newtheoremstyle{<style>}`.

Here are the basic styles that `amsthm` defines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\theoremstyle{theorem}\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} Some theorem. \end{theorem}
\begin{definition} Some definition. \end{definition}
\begin{remark} Some remark. \end{remark}
\end{document}
```

New styles have the following interface (taken directly from the [`amsthm` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf), section **4.3 New theorem styles**, p 4):

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% <name>
  {3pt}% <Space above>
  {3pt}% <Space below>
  {}% <Body font>
  {}% <Indent amount>
  {\itshape}% <Theorem head font>
  {:}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
  {.5em}% <Space after theorem head>
  {}% <Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')>
```

The custom theorem head specification is a little more tricky, details of which are included in the [AMS Class documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) (section **Custom theorem styles**, p 63):

> There is a `\newtheoremstyle` command provided to make the creation of
>   custom theorem styles fairly easy.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>                   #1
> \newtheoremstyle{NAME}%
>     #2          #3          #4
>   {ABOVESPACE}{BELOWSPACE}{BODYFONT}%
>     #5      #6        #7         #8
>   {INDENT}{HEADFONT}{HEADPUNCT}{HEADSPACE}%
>     #9
>   {CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC}
> ```
>
> Leaving the 'indent' argument empty is equivalent to entering `0pt`.
>   The 'headpunct' and 'headspace' arguments are for the punctuation and
>   horizontal space between the theorem head and the following text.
>   There are two special values that may be used for 'headspace': a
>   single space means that a normal interword space should be used;
>   "`\newline`" means that there should be a line break after the head
>   instead of horizontal space. The 'custom-head-spec' argument follows a
>   special convention: it is interpreted as the replacement text for an
>   internal three-argument function `\thmhead`, *i.e.*, as if you were
>   defining
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]{...#1...#2...#3...}
> ```
>
> but omitting the initial `\renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]`. The three
>   arguments that will be supplied to `\thmhead` are the name, number,
>   and optional note components. Within the replacement text you can (and
>   normally will want to) use other special functions `\thmname`,
>   `\thmnumber`, and `\thmnote`. These will print their argument if and
>   only if the corresponding argument of `\thmhead` is nonempty. For
>   example
>
> ```
> {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
> ```
>
> This would cause the theorem note `#3` to be printed with a preceding
>   space and enclosing parentheses, if it is present, and if it is
>   absent, the space and parentheses will be omitted because they are
>   inside the argument of `\thmnote`.
>
> Finally, if you have an extra bit of arbitrary code that you want to
>   slip in somewhere, the best place to do it is in the 'body font'
>   argument.
>
> The `\newtheoremstyle` command is designed to provide, through a
>   relatively simple interface, control over the style aspects that are
>   most commonly changed. More complex requirements must be addressed
>   through a separate LaTeX package.
>
> When you set up custom theorem styles with `\newtheoremstyle` you
>   should not use `\swapnumbers`. You have full control of the ordering
>   of elements in the theorem head, just place them where you want. Or,
>   if you do use `\swapnumbers`, you must look at the definition of
>   `\swappedhead` and change it appropriately.

Comment: this is very late, but ... at the top, you say that "`amsmath` provides three styles by default".  not `amsmath`, but `amsthm`.  (that's properly identified in the rest of the answer.  i figured i'd let you make the fix yourself.  do so, and i'll zap this comment.)