# Titles become 'unbolded' when adding in a new theoremstyle

Tags: theorems, bold

Up until now, whenever I create a new definition or theorem etc., the title (so the word 'Definition' etc.) would come up in bold. However, when I try to add '\theoremstyle{remark}', the titles stop coming up in boldface. Is there any way I can fix this (i.e. so I don't have to bold each title individually as it comes up)? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm very new to all this.

Comment: Yes there is. `\theoremstyle` sets how theorems will be printed from that point onward, so setting it to something like `remark` (which doesn't have a **bold** title will have exactly that effect. Could you provide the community with a use-case in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Ah, so at the moment I have the following:

\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\theoremstyle{corollary}
\theoremstyle{proposition}
\theoremstyle{lemma}
\theoremstyle{example}
\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

As remark is one of them, does this make all my theorem non bold?

Comment: Which theorem package do you use?

Comment: @Bernard amsthm

Comment: `\theoremstyle{remark} ` won't make bold title, but italic title.

Comment: I don't know it well (personally, I use `ntheorem`), buts, as far as I can remember, if you want to number your remarks, you should use the `definition` style. If you want unnumbered remarks (and, in addition, an automatic placement of end-of-proof symbol), `ntheorem` is more flexible.

Comment: @HarishKumar What I want is italics for remarks, and bold for everything else. But It has made everything into non-bold italics, not just remarks.

Comment: @Bernard So what I want to try and get is to have unnumbered remarks with an italic heading, whilst keeping definitions, theorems lemmas etc. with bold headings. Is there no easy way to do this with amsthm?

Comment: Simply use `\theoremstyle{remark}` and `\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}` in  your preamble. Put it *after*  your other `\newtheorem`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use them like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}
    This is a definition
  \end{definition}
  \begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{corollary}
    This is a corollary
  \end{corollary}
  \begin{proposition}
    This is a proposition
  \end{proposition}
  \begin{lemma}
    This is a lemma
  \end{lemma}
  \begin{example}
    This is an example
  \end{example}
  \begin{remark}
    This is a remark
  \end{remark}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the recommended style for a definition is `\theoremstyle{definition}`, which sets the text in roman.  more information regarding the three styles defined by `amsthm` (although not the type style used for the headings) is given in this answer: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38265/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Right.