# New theorem environment with manual theorem number

Tags: macros, numbering, environments, amsthm, newtheorem

I am wondering how to create a new theorem environment / style which allows me to insert the theorem number manually. That is, I am imagining something like

```
 \begin{newtheorem}{2.3'}[title]
      This is a theorem.
 \end{newtheorem}
```

to translate into

**Theorem 2.3'** (title)**.** This is a theorem.

As a second example,

```
 \begin{newtheorem}{A}[title]
      This is a theorem.
 \end{newtheorem}
```

should give

**Theorem A** (title)**.** This is a theorem.

How would one be able to define such a theorem environment with argument which is (apart from the manual insertion of the "number") identical to the usual theorem environment?

Note, if I add a `\label` to a theorem of this type, I would like the corresponding `\ref` command to print the theorem number defined in the argument. That is, in the above example `\ref` should print `2.3'`.

I would be grateful for any help with this! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quite easy! `;-)` <sup>1</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{manualtheoreminner}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{manualtheorem}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\themanualtheoreminner{#1}%
  \manualtheoreminner
}{\endmanualtheoreminner}

\begin{document}

\begin{manualtheorem}{2.3'}[title]\label{foo}
This is a theorem.
\end{manualtheorem}

\begin{manualtheorem}{A}[title]\label{baz}
This is a theorem.
\end{manualtheorem}

Here is \ref{foo} and \ref{baz}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> *Been there, done that.*

Comment: Pronto, prontissimo... mamma mia! :)

Comment: @Ruben *Son come il fulmine* `:-D`

Comment: prime would be better than apostrophe.  (just being pedantic.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's left to the OP to decide.

Comment: Note: does not work with `cleveref` out of the box.

Comment: If I could have, I would have given more than one UP to this solution!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can't define a theorem-like environment `newtheorem` as there is alredy the `\newtheorem` macro that defines those environments simply due to the name clash. Assume we have an environment `theorem`. Then you can locally change `\thetheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\thetheorem{2.3'}
\begin{theorem}[title]
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

When wrapping this into an own environment you don't need to group explicitly as the `\begin` and `\end` definitions take care of this:

```
\newenvironment{Apollo13theorem}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\thetheorem{#1}
  \theorem
}{\endtheorem}
```

The custom environment would then be used as requested by the OP:

```
\begin{Apollo13theorem}{A}[title]
  This is a theorem.
\end{Apollo13theorem}
```

[image: examples]

Answer (score 1):

A version using `\NewDocumentEnvironment`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytheorem}{m}%
  {\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{$\mathbf{#1}$}%
   \begin{theorem}
  }%
  {\end{theorem}}
\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}{2.3'}[note]\label{foo}
  This is a theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}{A}[note]\label{baz}
  This is a theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\ref{foo} and \ref{baz}.

\end{document}
```

[image]