# Theorem numbering with sub-theorem, without section number

Tags: numbering, amsmath, theorems, counters, ieeetran

I am using the `IEEEtran` class and `\usepackage{amsthm}`. How can I set a counter for the theorems, independent of the sections? Let's say my first theorem has three parts and my second theorem has two parts. How can I generate?:

Theorem 1.1

Theorem 1.2

Theorem 1.3

Theorem 2.1

Theorem 2.2

Comment: We can use manual theorem number available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391443/new-theorem-environment-with-manual-theorem-number)

Comment: What if the next theorem has no parts? It should be “Theorem 3”, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a dedicated counter variable -- called `mythmcounter`, say -- and create a dedicated theorem-like environment -- called `mythm`, say -- whose numbering is subordinated to the value of `mythmcounter`. Run the instruction `\stepcounter{mythmcounter}` as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{mythmcounter}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Theorem}[mythmcounter]

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{mythmcounter}
\begin{mythm} abc \end{mythm}
\begin{mythm} def \end{mythm}

\stepcounter{mythmcounter}
\begin{mythm} ghi \end{mythm}
\begin{mythm} jkl \end{mythm}
\begin{mythm} mno \end{mythm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understood the question in its full extent, but there should be `subtheorems` that have a theorem and a subtheorem number. The easiest way is to define a new `subtheorem` environment that uses the `theorem` counter as driver counter.

The first occurence of such a subtheorem needs a `\setcounter{theorem}{1}`, the next one (if followed directly a subtheorem) requires a `\stepcounter{theorem}` to force the resetting of the subtheorem counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{subtheorem}{Subtheorem}[theorem]

\begin{document}

\section{Foo section}
\setcounter{theorem}{1}
\begin{subtheorem}{Part one}
\end{subtheorem}


\begin{subtheorem}{Part two}
\end{subtheorem}


\begin{subtheorem}{Part three}
\end{subtheorem}

\stepcounter{theorem}
\begin{subtheorem}{Part one}
\end{subtheorem}


\begin{subtheorem}{Part two}
\end{subtheorem}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing `subequations` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{parenttheorem}
\newenvironment{subtheorems}{%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}%
  \protected@edef\theparenttheorem{\thetheorem}%
  \setcounter{parenttheorem}{\value{theorem}}%
  \setcounter{theorem}{0}%
  \def\thetheorem{\theparenttheorem.\arabic{theorem}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{theorem}{\value{parenttheorem}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This has no parts.
\end{theorem}

\begin{subtheorems}
\begin{theorem}
First part 2
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Second part 2
\end{theorem}
\end{subtheorems}

\begin{theorem}
This has no parts.
\end{theorem}

\begin{subtheorems}
\begin{theorem}
First part 4
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Second part 4
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Third part 4
\end{theorem}
\end{subtheorems}

\begin{theorem}
This has no parts.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]