# New Theorem Style : equivalent ConteXt and LateX

Tags: context

I used LaTeX for a long time before converting (with difficulty !) to ConteXt. For example, to define my new theorems, I used the amsthm package and I did this :

[New Theorem Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234676/new-theorem-style)

```
\newtheoremstyle{theoremdd}% name of the style to be used
   {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
   {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
   {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
   {0pt}% measure of space to indent
   {\bfseries}% name of head font
   {. ---}% punctuation between head and body
   { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}

\theoremstyle{theoremdd}
\newtheorem{thmd}{Theorem}[section]
```

[image]

Here is what I propose with ConteXt:

```
\setupenumerations[
   before={\blank},
   after={\blank},
   text=Théorème,
   alternative=serried,
   title=no,
   prefix=yes,
   prefixsegments=chapter,
   way=bysection,
   numberstopper={. ---},
   titlestyle=bold,
   style=italic,
   width=broad]


\defineenumeration[theorem]
```

Is this the right method ?

Comment: What is the expected output for your enumeration? When you show a image with the result from LaTeX it is easier to give you an answer for the ConTeXt setup.

Comment: I'd also set `title=yes`, so that you can use `\starttheorem[title=Pythagoras Theorem]`, which is similar to `\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras Theorem]` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to have the `---` in the numberstopper because then it will appear in the cross-references to that theorem as well.  Instead you want to use `headcommand` to add the dash between the title and the contents.  Additionally we want to set `distance=none` because I added the spacing in `headcommand` already.  Since you set `prefixsegments=chapter`, I guess you also intended to use `way=bychapter` (instead of `bysection`).

```
\setupenumerations
  [before={\blank},
   after={\blank},
   text=Théorème,
   alternative=serried,
   title=no,
   headcommand=\groupedcommand{}{~---~},
   distance=none,
   prefix=yes,
   prefixsegments=chapter,
   way=bychapter,
   numberstopper={.},
   titlestyle=bold,
   style=italic,
   width=broad]

\defineenumeration[theorem]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={First}]

  \starttheorem[reference={thm:knuth}]
    \input knuth
  \stoptheorem

  \starttheorem
    See \in{Theorem}[thm:knuth]
    \input ward
  \stoptheorem

\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Second}]

  \starttheorem
    \input zapf
  \stoptheorem

  \starttheorem
    \input tufte
  \stoptheorem

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Henri. Is it possible to have `Theorem 1.1` instead of `Theorem 1.1.` ?

Comment: @Fabrice Of course, just remove the `numberstopper={.}` (I thought you put it there, which is why I left it there).