# My "definition" environment is in italic

Tags: environments, italic

I obtained a TeX "pre-built" file in order to write for my college, but it so happens that every time I call a `definition` environment (which is defined in the file), it is always in italic. I am not fond of this particular aesthetic. Is there some way I can change this? I know I can `\emph` things in order to return them to normal, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Can you show how the `definition` environment is defined in the template?

Comment: you might find some useful information in this question: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine the `\definiton` macro which starts the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{definition}%% only for demo here
  {\itshape}
  {}
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
Everything is in italic
\end{definition}

Redefine the environment (should be in the pramble)
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\definition}{\upshape}
\makeatother

\begin{definition}
Everything is in upright
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```