# How to make examples without italic font?

Tags: theorems, italic

I'm doing a project and in my LaTeX file the examples are in italic. I want to know if there is something I can do to avoid it and put the examples in normal font. I did put the examples as "newtheorem".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That we can help ypou, please provide an minimal, complete document (minimal working example -- MWE), which show, your problem.

Comment: The English word for the French “police” is “font”. English “police” is French “policie”: quite a different thing. `;-)`

Comment: this might help: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Comment: Thank you! My problem is solved and I learned a new english word! ;)