# Deactivating italic text in body of a "definition" environment

Tags: theorems, italic

I definied a new theorem via

```
\newtheorem{def}{definition}
```

But the text has a italic font and i do not want that. how can i deactivate the italic font?

Comment: What package are you using to create your theorems?

Comment: Aside: LaTeX won't let you set up an environment called `def`. You'll get an error message such as `! LaTeX Error: Command \def already defined.`. Use `defn` or something else instead.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using a theorem-related package such as `amsthm`.  If that's the case, just issue the instruction

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
```

ahead of the instruction

```
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{defn}[Lipsum]
\lipsum*[2] % filler text
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use the `ntheorem` package rather than the `amsthm` package to set up theorem-like environments, you should replace `\theoremstyle{definition}` with `\theorembodyfont{\upshape}`.