# What kind of commands produce the "example" and "solution" headings in the picture

Tags: spacing

I've tried using flushleft with bolds such as

```
\begin{flushleft}{\medium{\textbf{Example 1}}\end{flushleft}
```

but that makes a large space right after.

Notice the text is all the way to the left of the pdf, there is minimal space between it and the next paragraph, the the paragraph is indented.

[image]

Comment: See the documentation of the `amsthm` and `ntheorem` packages.

Comment: See Section 4 of the documentation of the `amsthm` package.

Comment: You also can look at the `thmtools` package, which cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem`.

Comment: Altering which packages?

Comment: In that case, I suggest that you ask your professor exactly what means you are allowed to use.  I’m sure that she or he prefer that you consult her/him rather than the Internet community… ;-)

Comment: @Quantitative -- no alteration of package `amsthm` necessary.  see [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260) and the `amsthm` documentation (`texdoc amsthm`) for details.

Comment: You can delete the question yourself, no?

Comment: @Mico not if it has answers, and I have to say, if I lost 40 points because a user had 'changed their mind' I would be a bit disappointed and would like it to be a little more difficult for someone to do it on two other questions to 5 other answerers, that's usually counted as vandalism on SE

Comment: @Au101 - Good points!

Comment: Why is this being closed as offtopic? I understand the OP is basically vandalizing their own question, but the solution to that may be something like blocking the user or politely telling them not to edit this question anymore?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with `thmtools` to let you start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove    = \topsep,
  spacebelow    = \topsep,
  bodyfont      = \itshape,
  headpunct     = ,
  postheadspace = 1em]%
{definition}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove    = \topsep,
  spacebelow    = \topsep,
  headpunct     = ,
  postheadspace = \newline,
  postheadhook  = {\hspace*{\parindent}}]%
{example}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove    = \topsep,
  spacebelow    = \topsep,
  headpunct     = ,
  postheadspace = \newline,
  postheadhook  = {\hspace*{\parindent}}]%
{solution}

\declaretheorem[style=definition,name=Definition]{defn}

\declaretheorem[style=example,numberlike=defn,name=Example]{ex}

\declaretheorem[style=solution,numbered=no,name=Solution]{sol}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{defn}

\begin{ex}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{ex}

\begin{sol}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

and an example without theorems...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\newcounter{defn}
\newcommand{\Def}{\refstepcounter{defn}\vspace*{\topsep}\noindent\textbf{Definition \thedefn}\hspace*{1em}}
\newcommand{\Ex}{\refstepcounter{defn}\vspace*{\topsep}\noindent\textbf{Example \thedefn}\par}
\newcommand{\Sol}{\vspace*{\topsep}\noindent\textbf{Solution}\par}

\begin{document}
\Def{\itshape\lipsum*[2]}

\Ex\lipsum*[2]

\Sol\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it's an introduction to LaTeX, maybe the OP is looking to something manual and basic like

```
\noindent\textbf{Example}\par
\indent text text text
```

?

Answer (score 1):

A simple code with `ntheorem`. I don't think the 1st paragraph indent is nice, so I didn't set it. It can be inserted with a small patch of the `break` and `nonumberbreak`  theorem styles defined by ntheorem.

```
\documentclass{report}%]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\mdseries\hspace*{1em}}
\theoremseparator{\smallskip}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\renewcommand\theexample{\arabic{example}}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}


\begin{document}

\begin{example} \label{ex-1}
 Some example%
\end{example}

\begin{solution}
Some solution for example \ref{ex-1}. 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Quantitative:I tried to reproduce the image you posted, to make clear that all theorem-like (numbered) structures share the same counter. I can modify the code, but what's not clear to me is whether the vertical spacing between example and solution is OK for you?

Comment: @Quantative: I've modified my answer to a minimalistic one.