# In the Definition and Lemma body environment I want non italic content

Tags: italic

I am using a book style file and in the preamble I defined some theorem environment. But in the Definition and Lemma part I want nonitalic content. Please suggest. My preamble are

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
```

Comment: After so many years being a user of TeX.SE you have neither learned of a MWE nor how to format posts :-( And you mean `book` class file, most likely)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260/15925

Comment: Mr. Christian Hupfer ! Sorry I am not an expert of TeX like you, so I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Below suggestion is not good but it works...

```
\newtheorem{odefinition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{odefinition}\rm}\end{odefinition}}

\newtheorem{olemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newenvironment{lemma}{\begin{olemma}\rm}\end{olemma}}
```

Comment: Yes, it works - no it is not good style.  Much better is to use the `amsthm` package.

Comment: `\rm` has been obsolete and deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: Dear Andrew Swann ! As you suggested above, both are not working. When I am using amsthm then it is giving error already defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ntheorem` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{tm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tm}It happens that $2+2=4$\end{tm}
  \begin{lm}Why not?\end{lm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Sir ! This ntheorem is also not working. Actually, I am using a class file of a book given by the publisher.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel Can you please explain in which way it is not working?