# Numeration of theorems considering the depth (section, subsection ...)

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want the theorems to be numerated considering the depth, namely:

Chapter 1.

Theorem 1.1.

Section 1.1.

Theorem 1.1.1.

Subsection 1.1.1.

Theorem 1.1.1.1.

Theorem 1.1.1.2.

Theorem 1.1.1.3.

I have used different theorem types like

```
\newtheorem{th}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{thh}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{thhh}{Theorem}[subsection]
```

but if I change part of a section into a subsection I have to change all the theorem types within.

Is there any way to unify this?

Comment: Can you provide a [complete, minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates your *current* behaviour? What `\documentclass` are you using? What package are you using for creating your `\newtheorem`s? How do you add the trailing period `.` to your numbering?

Answer (score 2):

The following code updates `\thetheorem` - the counter representation of the `theorem` counter/environment - with a prefix that depends on the current sectional unit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\updatetheoremprefixfor}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \@namedef{#1}{\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\csname the#1\endcsname.\arabic{theorem}}
  \setcounter{theorem}{0}%
  \csname old#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\updatetheoremprefixfor{chapter}
\updatetheoremprefixfor{section}
\updatetheoremprefixfor{subsection}
\updatetheoremprefixfor{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\chapter|.
\end{theorem}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\section|.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\subsection|.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\subsection|.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\subsection|.
\end{theorem}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\section|.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\section|.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem within a \verb|\subsection|.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just added, verbatim, in the preamble as you have here. I also added into my document a few theorems as in the example above. The document processes just fine, with no errors, but no theorems are visible (the document is no different with and without the theorems). Here is what I added to the text:\begin{theorem} test \end{theorem} \begin{theorem} test 2 \end{theorem} \subsubsection{Homework Hint} \begin{theorem} test 3 \end{theorem}

Comment: @Mark: Does you `.log` end with by saying "x Page(s)` where `x` is not 0? I just want to confirm that TeX actually created some output... Are you using any additional theorem-related packages? Or perhaps defining your `theorem` environment using something else (like [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ))?

Comment: It says: Output written on Solutions.pdf (11 pages, 90526 bytes).

Comment: @Mark: Well, in order to help you efficiently, you'll have to supply me with code that replicates the problem; something I can't do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  After you asked for the page output, I noticed it was far smaller than the size of the document, so I took out those lines, and the full document processed.  When I put them back, it worked.  I should have thought of trying this, but you got me started.  Thanks again...

Comment: One last question @Werner .  How can I make the text not be in italics?

Comment: @Mark: You can use [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)'s `\theoremstyle` to set one that doesn't use *italics*. Alternatively, you can define your own using `\theoremstyle{<new style>}`. See [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260/5764).