# Counters within subsections

Tags: numbering

I am writing a physics book where the problems are NOT at the end of the chapter but immediately follow material that is presented within sections.  As such, I cannot use `\enumerate` to number equations.  Instead, if there are two problems in Chapter 1, Section 2, I want them to be labeled 1.2-1 and 1.2-2, and so on.  And then in the next sections, the problems should start again

> Chapter 1 History
>
> 1.1 Intro
>
> TEXT TEXT TEXT
>
> 1.2 Theory
>
> TEXT TEXT TEXT
>
> Problem 1.2-1 Derive the ...
>
> TEXT TEXT TEXT
>
> Problem 1.2-2 Determine...
>
> Text Text Text
>
> 1.3 Time reversal
>
> Text
>
> Problem 1.3-1 Bla Bla Bla.
>
> 1.3.1 Fallacies
>
> TEXT
>
> Problem 1.3.1-1 Bla Bla Bla

You get the picture.  I would like to have a counter that automatically resets with a new chapter or section or subsection is started. Now I am using "`Problem \ref{label}-x`" where I supply the "x" manually -- not very LaTeX-like.  And also a pain when I add a problem to the middle of a section.

Comment: just declare the problem using `\newtheorem` (from the format or one of the many theorem packages) that has an optional argument to say the counter should be reset every section

Comment: What you're after is essentially the same as what is covered in [Numeration of theorems considering the depth (section, subsection ...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413113/5764). The difference is you'll be called them `problem`s, not `theorem`s and adjust the display of the `problem` counter slightly - `1.3.1-1` instead of `1.3.1.1`. The process is automated, so you don't have to supply the `x` you're talking about.

Comment: I just added, verbatim, in the preamble as in the link you suggested.  I also added into the text a few theorems as in the example.  The document processes just fine, but no theorems are visible.  Here is what I added to the text:\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
test 2
\end{theorem}

\subsubsection{Homework Hint}

\begin{theorem}
test 3
\end{theorem}