# Font style in newtheorem

Tags: newtheorem

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

This is a proof:

\begin{solution}
abcdef
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

Although I tried several attempts, I was not able to change the font style in solution environment. Basically, I would like normal font instead of italics. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `\theoremstyle{definition}` before `\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}`.

Comment: @egreg. Thanks a lot. It works. I have tried with \theoremstyle before.....but I did not put definition inside curly brackets. Thanks again.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)