# Switch body font shape of newtheorem automatically

Tags: fonts, amsthm, emphasis

It is interesting that `\emph` will switch the shape of font automatically based on the current font is italic or not, e.g.,

```
\emph{This is \emph{non-italic} italic}.
```

will produce something like：

> *This is* non-italic *italic*

There are some cases I would like do the same for the body of a theorem. As far as I know, the theorem style is defined as

```
\newtheoremstyle{mythm} % name
{\topsep}               % Space above
{\topsep}               % Space below
{\itshape}              % Body font
{}                      % Indent amount
{\scshape}              % Theorem head font
{.}                     % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}                  % Space after theorem head
{}                      % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

An direct replace of the `\itshape` (option for Body font) by `\emph` is not working, I believe this is because `\itshape` is a switch (used by `{\itshape text}`) while `\emph` is a command (used by `\emph{text}`). The definition of `\emph` is (from latex by `texdef -t latex -c minimal -F emph`):

```
\emph :
\long macro:#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\em #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}
\em \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi
```

while

```
\itshape :
\long macro:->\not@math@alphabet \itshape \mathit \fontshape \itdefault \selectfont
```

Any idea?

**THE　MME**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheoremstyle{mythm} % name
{\topsep}               % Space above
{\topsep}               % Space below
{\itshape}              % Body font
{}                      % Indent amount
{\scshape}              % Theorem head font
{.}                     % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}                  % Space after theorem head
{}                      % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{mythm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
This is a test

\emph{This is \emph{non-italic} italic}.

\begin{thm}
  This is italic
\end{thm}
\itshape
This is a test
\begin{thm}
  This should be non-italic
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The non-macro version of `\emph` is called `\em`. What exactly is your use case for this? To me it would seem to be strange to have an upright theorem al of a sudden

Comment: @daleif  you r right, but replace `\itshape` with `\em` not work for me, I mean if the theorem is surrounded by italic fonts, then we should use the upright font shape instead.

Comment: I still don't see the use case, all theorems should look the same. I had a look in the `amsthm` sources (loaded by `amsart`). It issues `\normalfont` in an internal component and thus counters the `\itshape`. Without it, it does work, but as a reader I'd find it strange that the body font is not the same for all theorems

Comment: why don't you just use `\theoremstyle{definition}`?  it's identical in characteristics to `\theoremstyle{plain}` *except* for the fact that the body is upright roman.  see [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260) for some commentary.

Answer (score 3):

Internally `amsthm` (auto loaded by `amsthm`) issues a `\normalfont` at the start of every theorem construction, thus counter the external `\itshape`.

You can patch `\@thm` to remove it...:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm{\normalfont}{}{}{\NOPE}
\makeatother
```

This will fail (aka run the non-existing `\NOPE`) if the patching fails