# How do you make different theoremstyle

Tags: environments, theorems

When preparing some manuscript, I noticed it is required that theorem, definition and remark have different formats.

> vi) Theorems etc. The words “Theorem”, “Lemma”, “Corollary”,
>   “Proposition” and “Definition” (and their appropriate numerals) are to
>   appear in bold face. The complete body of a theorem, lemma, corollary
>   and proposition is to appear in italics. Only the concept to be
>   defined in a definition is to appear in italics, the rest of the
>   definition being in ordinary print. The words “Proof ”, “Remark”,
>   “Comment”, “Note”, “Example”, etc. are to appear in italics.

I was using `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` for all theorems, corollaries, remarks, examples, etc... I was only able to set one style using `\theoremstyle{}`

Is there a way that I can set different styles for different environments?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you employ a theorem-creation package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`.

Comment: @Mico I'm using the amsthm package

Comment: `thmtools` can help in defining theorem styles, and it cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem`.

Comment: Please read section 4, entitled "Changing styles for theorem-like environments" of the user guide of the `amsthm` package? (To open a copy of this user guide in a browser, type `texdoc amsthm` at a command prompt.) The `amsthm` package provides three standard theorem styles: `plain`, `definition`, and `remark`. Use`\theoremstyle{...}` to switch among theorem styles. In addition, if you're not satisfied with existing theorem styles, you could use the `\newtheoremstyle` macro to create new theorem styles; see subsection 4.3 on p. 9 of the user guide for more about `\newtheoremstyle`.

Comment: Potential duplicate, at least regarding italic vs. upright text: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)