# How to customize \newtheorem

Tags: formatting, theorems

I was wondering if there's a way to remove italic text format in environment created with \newtheorem command.

Here is my code:

```
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[subsection]
```

In `\begin{document}`:

```
\begin{teorema}
    This is a new theorem.
\end{teorema}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The problem is that I don't want the text to be italic. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy if you use `amsthm`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[subsection]
```

---

I can't recommend numbering theorems according to subsections, for a couple of reasons. First, you are compelled to use subsections, which is not always necessary; second, if the class has chapters, you end up with theorems with *four* numbers.

I can't recommend using upright type either, because italics give a visual clue for finding the statements more easily.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for solving my problem. What should I use to number theorems?

Answer (score 0):

The way in which `\newtheorem` works and in which environments defined in terms of `\newtheorem` can be patched depends on the documentclass and the packages in use.

Using the article-class and no packages, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[subsection]
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\Oldteorema{\let\Oldteorema=\teorema}%
\renewcommand\teorema{\@ifnextchar[{\teoremaopt}{\Oldteorema\normalfont}}%
\newcommand\teoremaopt[1][]{\Oldteorema[{#1}]\normalfont}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{teorema}
    This is a new theorem.
\end{teorema}

\begin{teorema}[someone]
    This is a new theorem.
\end{teorema}


\end{document}
```

I give no warranties that this works with other documentclasses, e.g., beamer.

Did you consider using the [amsthm-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) with its `\newtheoremstyle`/`\theoremstyle`-commands?

Comment: This would break cases such as `\begin{teorema}[Someone]`.

Comment: @egreg Ooops....  Thanks. (I think I rectified the thing now.)