# LyX and AMS book: how to add a new item in menu?

Tags: lyx, amsbook

I am working with LyX-2.3.4.2 -->  Document class --> "American Mathematical Society (AMS) Book".

On the left-hand menu, I note (French version):

- Standard
- Sectionnement
- NonNuméroté
- Préliminaires
- Compléments
- Démonstration

  ```
    -Théorème
    -Conjecture
    -Définition
    -Exercice
    -etc...
  ```

Within the "Démonstration" section (*i.e.*, at the same level than "Théorème" or "Exercice", I need to use some new items such as "Conseil" (for Tip), "Avertissement" (for Warning).

I used 'find' and 'grep' commands in order to identify the locations of "Conjecture" or "Théorème" (ditto in English). Without success.

Could you help me to find a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Thierry

Comment: `amsbook` has the `amsthm` definitions built in.  I don't know how to add new definitions to LyX, but I believe you can add new theorem objects in the same way you would add them if you were entering ordinary LaTeX code.  The options are presented in an answer to this question: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found according to [amsthdoc.pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570879/lyx-and-ams-book-how-to-add-a-new-item-in-menu?noredirect=1#comment1438559_570879):

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{tip}{Conseil}
\begin{tip}
    Indiquer un conseil...
\end{tip}
```

In LyX, this code must be placed in a TeX "red" box (amsbook: no need to insert something the preamble).