# font is automatically coming in italics for definitions and remarks

Tags: thesis, italic

I am using the following thesis template to write my thesis.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{a4wide}% obsolete: geometry does a better job
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig} obsolete: graphicx does the job
\usepackage{palatino,float,multicol,fancybox,amsfonts,appendix,amsthm}%shadow
%subfigure is deprecated. Use subcaption instead
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage[emindex]{apacite}
%\usepackage{authorindex}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{fancy} \makeindex %\authorindex

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.1pt}
%\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0.01cm}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}} \fancyfoot{}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\date{\today}
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000

\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{graphics} useless: graphicx is loaded
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} useless. utf8 is the default nowadays, unless otherwise specified
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,amsxtra, setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, eso-pic}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{scalerel, stackengine}
\stackMath

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}%
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\allowdisplaybreaks

% THEOREM Environments ---------------------------------------------------
%\setlength{\textheight}{19.5 cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{12.5 cm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}[theorem]{Hypothesis}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\mainidx}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{{\bf #1}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
        \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
    \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
    \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}

\renewcommand{\d}{\/\mathrm{d}\/}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------

% Macro for 'List of Symbols', 'List of Notations' etc...
\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \cleardoublepage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}

\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true, % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false, % non-Latin characters in Acrobat�s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true, % show Acrobat�s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true, % show Acrobat�s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false, % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH}, % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title}, % title
    pdfauthor={Author}, % author
    pdfsubject={Subject}, % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator}, % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true, % links in new window
    colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue, % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue, % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta, % color of file links
    urlcolor=green % color of external links
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand {\apgt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel>\over\sim$}}\ }
\newcommand {\aplt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel<\over\sim$}}\ }

\makeatletter
\def\myfnt{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\newpage
\doublespace\include{Title} \pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}1
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%TOC

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % organisational level that receives a numbers
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % print table of contents for level 3
\tableofcontents
% levels are: 0 - chapter, 1 - section, 2 - subsection, 3 - subsection
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\listoffigures %\listoftables

\newpage
%\doublespace\chapter*{List of Symbols\hfill} \markboth{List of
%Symbols}{List of Symbols} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of
%Symbols} \listofsymbols \cleardoublepage
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listoffigures,\listoftables}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} \doublespace
\include{Preliminaries}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
%\include{chapter6a}
%\include{chapter6b}
%\include{chaptercon}
%\begin{appendices}
%\input{AppendixA}
%\input{AppendixB}
%\end{appendices}

%\def\Appendix{\input{Appendix_1} \cleardoublepage}
%\chapter*{Appendix\hfill} \markboth{Appendix}{Appendix} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
%\Appendix \cleardoublepage
%\include{Appendix_1}
%\include{bibit}

 %The style you want to use for references.
%\bibliography{mr,refs}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}\chapter*{Publications arising out of the PhD thesis\hfill} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications arising
out of the PhD thesis}
%\begin{center}\textbf{\Large Publications arising out of the PhD thesis}\end{center}{\huge \par}
%\bigskip{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item [{[1]}]  qq
\end{enumerate}
\clearpage
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bigskip{}
\vspace{1cm} \cleardoublepage


%\printindex %Make an index AUTOMATICALLY

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\singlespace
\printindex %\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

When I write definition or remark, the font is showing as italics.

How can I change this?

As a side question, are there any commands in above template that are not necessary? I do not know much about technicalities, I only know how to write in latex. So, I copied the template from some one. Please let me know if any of them are unnecessary or if this template can be made any better.

Please see the attached photo for error after using the template mentioned by  Bernard.

[image]

Comment: Some packages are obsolete. You don't need to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools` (which is a superset of amsmath). Some packages are loaded twice. Last, `hyperref`  should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions.

Comment: @Bernard Ok. Is there any thing else that is obsolete?

Comment: can you also help me to fix italics issue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  It seems you got an answer about the italics.  Are you posting the bounty to help solve the error message?  That would have been better asked as a new question.  Regardless, it's not caused by what you've shown.  It looks like it's coming from a line containing the phrase "be vector fields on".  Could you search for that in your tex file?

Comment: @Teepeemm I have searched for that, there is only one instance; that is "Let $X,Y\colon M\rightarrow TM$ be vector fields on $M$".. I do not know why it is showing error here..

Comment: I added the whole .tex file of the template. Can some one see if there is any issue with the template?

Comment: If you delete or comment out that line, what happens to the error?  If you delete everything else, what happens to the error?  If you delete everything else and then delete packages that aren't being used for that line, what happens to the error?

Comment: @Teepeemm Ok. I think I understand what is the problem.. If I am writing $X,Y:M\rightarrow TM$ there is no error. If I am writing $X,Y\colon M\rightarrow TM$ there is an error as mentioned above,, In other places also I have written $\colon$ but it is not showing any error in those places

Comment: If you delete that line and retype it character by character, does that help?  Which IDE are you using?  Can you open up the actual .log file and look for that error, instead of what the IDE is reporting?

Comment: This file loads the `amsthm` package.  This should answer your question: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Comment: The error message shown in the photo is truncated, so it may not be showing the actual cause of the error.  You should look at the log file, and copy the error from there; it will be more than one line long.

Comment: Off topic: `\d` is already defined (it is an accent) and really shouldn't be redefined.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I coped the error from log file :O thanks for the comment about \d

Comment: I see that the photo has the "log file" box highlighted.  But the log file has been reformatted, and important parts of the error information have been truncated.  You need to look at the log file at the system level, not through the "front end" program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/non-italic-text-in-theorems-definitions-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the italic problem. I just added the theorem style for these theorem structure, respectively `definition` and `remark`.

I also cleaned the duplicate loadings, and added comments on obsolete or deprecated packages.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{a4wide}% obsolete: geometry does a better job
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig} obsolete: graphicx does the job
\usepackage{palatino,float,multicol,fancybox,amsfonts,appendix,amsthm}%shadow
%subfigure is deprecated. Use subcaption instead
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage[emindex]{apacite}
%\usepackage{authorindex}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{fancy} \makeindex %\authorindex

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.1pt}
%\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0.01cm}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}} \fancyfoot{}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\date{\today}
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000

\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{graphics} useless: graphicx is loaded
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} useless. utf8 is the default nowadays, unless otherwise specified
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,amsxtra, setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, eso-pic}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{scalerel, stackengine}
\stackMath

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}%
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\allowdisplaybreaks

% THEOREM Environments ---------------------------------------------------
%\setlength{\textheight}{19.5 cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{12.5 cm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}[theorem]{Hypothesis}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\mainidx}[1]{{\it #1}}
  \newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{{\bf #1}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
        \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
    \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
    \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}

\renewcommand{\d}{\/\mathrm{d}\/}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------

% Macro for 'List of Symbols', 'List of Notations' etc...
\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \cleardoublepage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}

\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true, % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false, % non-Latin characters in Acrobat�s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true, % show Acrobat�s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true, % show Acrobat�s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false, % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH}, % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title}, % title
    pdfauthor={Author}, % author
    pdfsubject={Subject}, % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator}, % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true, % links in new window
    colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue, % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue, % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta, % color of file links
    urlcolor=green % color of external links
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand {\apgt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel>\over\sim$}}\ }
\newcommand {\aplt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel<\over\sim$}}\ }

\makeatletter
\def\myfnt{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{definition}
  $0$ is the first natural number.
\end{definition}
Some more text. Some more text

\begin{remark}
Some authors, contrary to Giuseppe Peano, do not consider consider that $0\in\mathbf{N}$.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting the following error "\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 TM$ \OT1/bch/m/n/10.95 be vec-tor fields on $\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 M$\OT1/bch/m/n/10.95 . Then, $\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 ^^H([\OML/cmm/m/it/10."

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I don't have such a message, which seems strange. Are you sure it is an *error* message?

Comment: Please see the edit... I have taken screenshot of the error message...

Comment: I see. The problem comes  quite probably from `charter`. Do you really need this font, and if so, can you replace it with `xcharter`? For the warning about `\headheight`, it is quite easy to solve with `geometry`, but the values of the required margins should be known to use this package.

Comment: It says "File `xcharter.sty' not found. \usepackage"

Comment: Install it with your package manager. What  is your distribution?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Well, install with TeX Live Package manager.

Comment: I have added the complete .tex file. Can you see if anything is wrong with the template?