# How to modularise part of the article?

Tags: formatting

I have some examples in my article, and I would like to modularise them so the readers can easily identify and skip them.

One option is to put the whole example (including both English and math equations) into the "example" environment (a variant of the theorem environment). In this case, everything is Italic. I am a little bit worried because I have three consecutive examples and would have three pages of Italic as a result.

The other option is to add a black square at the end of the example.

Which one or anything else is better? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not a direct solution but theorem-style environments needn't be all-italic: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Answer (score 1):

a few options:

- reduce the length of the examples, i.e. fill less than 3 pages
- have a short paragraph of normal text (e.g. this text is the main flow, while the examples just illustrate what was just said
- use `\hrule` as a visual separator
- try a different organization of your content so the examples "flow in" more naturally
- modify the appearance of your example environment, e.g. indent it a little, use frames, put a symbol (see e.g. the O'Reily book series).

In summary I think your request is more related to content and less to layout or typesetting. Which is not a bad thing, but infringe with the goals of this Q&A-approach taken here.