# How to change the contents of a theorem-like environment from italic to upright lettering?

Tags: environments, amsthm, italic

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,authblk,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]     
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section] 
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}


\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\date{}
\title{Title}
\author{}
\affil{}

\begin{document}
%   \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        
                
    \end{abstract}
    
    \textbf{Keywords:} 
    \\
    \\
    \textbf{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification:} 
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{Sec1}
    
    \begin{example}
        This is an example.
    \end{example}
    
        \begin{note}
            This is a note.
        \end{note}
    
    \begin{lemma}
        This is a lemma.
    \end{lemma}
     
     \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem.
     \end{theorem}
 \begin{proof}
    This is a proof.
 \end{proof}
\begin{definition}
    This is a definition.
\end{definition}
        
    %\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

The above is a minimal working code for writing an academic paper.
My problem is whenever I am using the environments "definition, theorem, example, note" etc, everything under it gets written down in **italics.**
But if I write anything under `\begin{proof} \end{proof}`, it gets written down in **normal** font. Can someone please say why it happens.
I have shown it in the code attached above.

I want to write everything under the environment `\begin{example} \end{example}` in normal fonts. Is that possible?

Another question is that can we modify the environments *definition, theorem, example, note* in such a way that we can write the contents under it in whatever way we wish i.e. we can control whether it will be italic or in normal font.

If someone can please help me out, I will be thankful.

Comment: that is the default style for theorem like environments defined by `amsthm` you can see the package documentation to use or define other styles

Comment: Off-topic: `\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}` may (and should...) be simplified to `\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}` since (a) `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically and (b) `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically.

Comment: You're using `amsthm`.  Use `\theoremstyle{definition}`.  (Duplicate: [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260).)

Comment: @barbarabeeton; thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with two excerpts from section 4, "Changing styles for theorem-like environments", of the user guide of the `amsthm` package [yellow highlighting added]:

[image]

[image]

---

You asked,

> I want to write everything [in] the environment `example` in normal fonts. Is that possible?

Yes. Either the `definition` or the `remark` theorem style should be appropriate for your use case.

You further wrote,

> Another question is that can we modify the environments `definition`, `theorem`, `example`, `note` in such a way that we can write the contents under it in whatever way we wish i.e. we can control whether it will be italic or in normal font[?]

The answer is also "Yes". I would strongly encourage you to read subsection 4.3, "New theorem styles", of the user guide of the `amsthm` package.

---

Note the use of upright lettering in the `example` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{amsthm}
% \theoremstyle{plain} %% that's the default
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section] 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{definition} % <-- switch to a different theorem style
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}


\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}

\begin{note}
This is a note.
\end{note}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}
 
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so very much.