# Formatting examples: newtheorem

Tags: formatting, newtheorem

I am using the `\newtheorem` command for several things: theorems, lemmas, propositions,... But also examples. By default, `\newtheorem` writes everything in italics. I want everything in italics but the examples. If I use `\theoremstyle{definition}` neither of them are in italics, but this is not what I want. How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might consider using a package that provides the flexibility you want.  This question (possible duplicate) offers one possibility: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260

Answer (score 1):

Despite you did not provide a minimal example, you are probably in need of `\theoremstyle{plain}` or similar. C. f. subsection 4.1 in the [documentation](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) of amsthm.

PS: Thanks to @dexteritas for pointing out the missing minimal example.