# Constructing \definition in latex

Tags: definition

Does there exist `\begin{definition}` in latex?  And how can I construct one?  Is everything derived from `\newtheorem` command.

Comment: Not an answer, but I suggest that you read something listed here to get started: [getting started with latex](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-man-latex).

Comment: How about `\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\textbf{Definition: } #1}` or perhaps clarify what you mean by "definition". --- GOM

Comment: I want to understand what is already available.  There exists `\begin{theorem}`.  And it seems there is also `\begin{corollary}`.  What else is there?

Comment: From what I have seen, definitions, lemmas, and corollaries are customarily defined using a theorem style.

Comment: From my understanding, there is no predefined theorem environments. Latex only offer  the command `\newtheorem` to define one by user. If you can use `\begin{theorem}` or `\begin{corollary}`. Those must be defined in your `class` file or some packages. Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @Ephram There are many defined environments, such as `quote`, `verse`, `align` and so on. It seems that you are after a complete list of LaTeX environments whether they are in basic LaTeX or any of the multitude of packages. --- GOM

Comment: Just in basic Latex that comes with the installation.  If latex only offers the command `\newtheorem` then the remaining can be defined from there.  And thus answer my question.

Comment: `amsthm` provides d `definition` environment.  See  [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260) for details.  (This is the style used in publications of the American Math Society; I was a member of the AMS publications technical support team before retirement, so I should be considered biased.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, there is no predefined theorem environments. Latex only offer the command `\newtheorem` to define one by user. If you can use `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` or `\begin{corollary}...\end{corollary}`. Those must be defined in your `class` file or some `packages`. Correct me if I was wrong.

If you want deeply understand how the `\newtheorem` command defined in basic Latex code. Here is the section which define `\newtheorem` in `latex.ltx` file.

```
%%% From File: ltthm.dtx
\def\newtheorem#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@othm{#1}}{\@nthm{#1}}}
\def\@nthm#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@xnthm{#1}{#2}}{\@ynthm{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@xnthm#1#2[#3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}\@newctr{#1}[#3]%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{%
       \expandafter\noexpand\csname the#3\endcsname \@thmcountersep
          \@thmcounter{#1}}%
     \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#1}{#2}}%
     \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}
\def\@ynthm#1#2{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#1}}%
     \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#1}{#2}}%
     \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}
\def\@othm#1[#2]#3{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocounterr{#2}}%
    {\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\global\@namedef{the#1}{\@nameuse{the#2}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#2}{#3}}%
  \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}}
\def\@thm#1#2{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@ythm{#1}{#2}}{\@xthm{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@xthm#1#2{%
  \@begintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\ignorespaces}
\def\@ythm#1#2[#3]{%
  \@opargbegintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#3}\ignorespaces}
\def\@thmcounter#1{\noexpand\arabic{#1}}
\def\@thmcountersep{.}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\itshape}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)}]\itshape}
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no predefined `theorem` environment, nor `corollary`.

There are perhaps packages providing them, but you give no information about the packages you load.

Since the repertoire of such statements is really vast and every user will have their own preferences (language for the headers, names and so on), LaTeX just provides the generic `\newtheorem` facility.

I recommend loading `amsthm` that adds flexibility, still keeping the same syntax.

In your preamble you will have something like

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition} % the body will be in upright type
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Several variations are possible, check with any good LaTeX guide.