# How to change the font inside a \begin{defi} environment

Tags: fonts, environments, format

I have the following issue. In my LaTeX, I use the following formats:

```
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{nota}{Nota}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observación}
```

So when I compile, for example:

```
\begin{defi}
Un semigrupo es un par $(S,\cdot)$ donde $S$ es un conjunto y $S\times S\to S$ operación asociativa, i.e. $(s_1s_2)s_3=s_1(s_2s_3)~\forall s_1,s_2,s_3\in S$.
\end{defi}
\begin{defi}
Un monoide $(M,\cdot)$ es un semigrupo con un elemento neutro $e\in M$.
\end{defi}
\begin{obs}
El neutro del monoide es único.
\end{obs}
\begin{defi}
Un grupo $G$ es un monoide con inversos: $\forall g\in G~\exists g^{-1}\in G$ tal que $gg^{-1}=g^{-1}g=e$.
\end{defi}
\begin{obs}
El inverso es único.
\end{obs}
\begin{defi}
Un grupo (o semigrupo o monoide) se dice abeliano o conmutativo si $$g_1g_2=g_2g_1~\forall g_1,g_2\in G$$.
\end{defi}
```

it prints
[image]

I would like to change the font inside each definition, theorem, observation, etc. Instead of a cursive-wise or italic, I'd use a more standard one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be considered a duplicate of [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say what package you're using for defining theorems and theorem-like environments. I'm assuming you're using `amsthm` but there are others (like `ntheorem`).

The style applied to the theorem environment is determined by the most recent `\theoremstyle` command selected prior to the `\newtheorem` command for that environment.

The `plain` style you're using makes the text italics. There's another style, `definition` (appropriately enough for your use case) that does not. So select it prior to  `\newtheorem{defi}...`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}% no theoremstyle selected, so the default (plain) is used
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}% uses plain style
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}% uses plain style
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposici\'on}% uses plain style
\newtheorem{nota}{Nota}% uses plain style
\newtheorem{obs}{Observación}% uses plain style

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}% uses definition style

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Un semigrupo es un par $(S,\cdot)$ donde $S$ es un conjunto y $S\times S\to S$ operación asociativa, i.e. $(s_1s_2)s_3=s_1(s_2s_3)~\forall s_1,s_2,s_3\in S$.
\end{defi}
\begin{defi}
Un monoide $(M,\cdot)$ es un semigrupo con un elemento neutro $e\in M$.
\end{defi}
\begin{obs}
El neutro del monoide es único.
\end{obs}
\begin{defi}
Un grupo $G$ es un monoide con inversos: $\forall g\in G~\exists g^{-1}\in G$ tal que $gg^{-1}=g^{-1}g=e$.
\end{defi}
\begin{obs}
El inverso es único.
\end{obs}
\begin{defi}
Un grupo (o semigrupo o monoide) se dice abeliano o conmutativo si \[g_1g_2=g_2g_1~\forall g_1,g_2\in G\].
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

[image: upright definitions]

If you want all of the others to work like that as well, move them to after the `\theoremstyle{definition}` command as well.

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{nota}{Nota}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observación}
```

It's also possible to define your own theorem styles. See the [amsthm documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) for details.

(This is unrelated, but `$$ ... $$` for display math is outdated for LaTeX; use `\[...\]` instead. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).)

Comment: Thank you very very much, you literally saved my life.

Comment: Literally? If someone was threatening your life based on font styles in your LaTeX document, you should contact the police, not post on SE. :-) But you're welcome anyway.